# Socratic badge: did I meet the criteria or not?

Tags: support, badges

I *think* when I asked this [question about k-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260820/is-sparks-kmeans-unable-to-handle-bigdata) I got a:

> Next badge 100/100

[badge:Socratic]

However, it doesn't seem I have been awarded this badge, and that's OK; I just would like the reasoning behind this. I mean I have waited for >24h. Should I wait more, or do I not meet the criteria, or something?